# Estimated value and GMM

Tags: statistics, conditional-expectation

I have a question.

We have the following model:

$y_t=\delta+\phi y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$

$\epsilon^2_t=\varpi+\alpha \epsilon^2_{t-1}+v_t$

with $|\phi|<1, \varpi>0, \alpha \geq0$

and that:

E($\epsilon_t$|$I_{t-1}$)=E($v_t$|$I_{t-1}$)=0. (1.1)

I have to show that:

E($\epsilon_t$)=E($\epsilon_t$$y_{t-i})$=E($\epsilon_t$$y^2_{t-i}$)=0 (1.2)

E($v_t$)=E($v_t$$y_{t-i}$)=E($v_t$$y^2_{t-i}$)=0 (1.3)

for all i=1,2,... given (1.2)

Furthermore, I have need to find how this result can be used to derive a generalized method of moments, GMM, estimator for $\theta$. I have to write the  population moment conditions using instruments $z_t=(1,y_{t-1},y^2_{t-1})'$ as well as the corresponding sample moment conditions. How many moment conditions, R, and number of parameters, K, would there be?

**My thoughts so far:**

Since condition (1.1) is equal to zero, I thought that one might be able to do this:

$E(\epsilon_t)=E(\epsilon_t y_{t-i})=E(\epsilon_t y^2_{t-i})=0$
<=>
$E(\epsilon_t)=E(\epsilon_t)*E(y_{t-i})=E(\epsilon_t)*E(y^2_{t-i})=
0*E(y^2_{t-i})=0$

Regarding the GMM part of the question, I have no idea how to proceed.

Can anyone help me with this, please?